# Can anyone explain what Installshield is doing when it creats a copy of its setup.exe, which it calls something pseudo-random, like _is12345.exe?

Tags: installshield

We create InstallShield suite packages internally (usually a bundle of other various software packages and PowerShell scripts to customize our installs).  Lately there has been some strange behaviour and we are thinking virus software may be at the root of it.  Trying to understand what InstallShield is doing exactly when it creates these child processes.  Any info appreciated.

Comment: InstallShield can explain that, can't they?

Comment: I can't seem to find this information